# Waf: How to output a generated file?

Tags: python, build, waf

I have a file I want to send to the build directory after it's been pushed through a python script.  How would I do this in waf?

For example, if I had a file like this:

```
VERSION=%%VERSION%%
DATADIR=%%DATADIR%%
```

And wanted to replace %%VERSION%% and %%DATADIR%% before outputing that to the waf build directory, how would I do that?

I know it's something along the lines of:

```
ctx(rule='???'
 source='versionfile.ver', 
 target='versionfile.out'
)
```

But I don't know what the rule would be.

Also, once that file is generated, is it possible to use it in other tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to substitute an input file your versionfile.ver should look like this

```
VERSION=@VERSION@
DATADIR=@DATADIR@
```

Now you can use the following task so the values will be substituted

```
bld.new_task_gen (
  features = "subst",
  source= "versionfile.ver",
  target= "versionfile.out",
  VERSION = bld.env['VERSION'],
  DATADIR = bld.env['DATADIR'])
```

To be able to access version from bld you have to define it during configure

```
conf.env['VERSION'] = '0.7.0'
```

You can find this waf task in action [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~diodon-team/diodon/trunk/view/head:/data/wscript_build) Output files of this tasks can than be used as input for other tasks.

However when you want to pass on your source file through a python script or any command available you can use the following:

```
lib_typelib = bld.new_task_gen(
  name = 'versionfile',
  source = 'versionfile.ver',
  target = 'versionfile.out',
  rule='/path/to/your/python/script ${SRC} -o ${TGT}')
```

There is also a sample available [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~diodon-team/diodon/trunk/view/head:/libdiodon/wscript_build) where in this case g-ir-compiler is used what in your case would be a python script.

Comment: the subst feature is exactly what I was looking for, which I hadn't seen before.